# Как использовать CloseHandle

Tags: c++, winapi

Написал программу, которая последовательно запускает 3 другие программы, все работает, но я не уверен что все грамотно написано, так как не знаю как что работает), должен ли я прописывать CloseHandle после каждого запуска процесса или только в конце программы, хочу услышать ваши замечания, вот пример кода:

```
int cn = 30;

STARTUPINFOA si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

string path;
string path1;
string path2;
ifstream fin;
ofstream check;

// Запускаю первую программу и жду ее завершения
path1 = "\"C:\\Users\\Acer\\YandexDisk\\latest version\\StBuilderMul\\Debug\\StBuilderMul.exe\"";
path2 = "C:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\Monday\\case";
path = path1 + " " + path2 + " " + to_string(cn);
CreateProcess(NULL, const_cast<LPSTR>(path.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);


// Запускаю вторую программу и жду ее завершения
path1 = "\"C:\\Users\\Acer\\YandexDisk\\latest version\\Stochastic\\Debug\\Stochastic.exe\"";
path2 = "C:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\Monday\\case";
path = path1 + " " + path2 + " " + to_string(cn);
CreateProcess(NULL, const_cast<LPSTR>(path.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

// Запускаю третью программу и жду ее завершения
path1 = "\"C:\\Users\\Acer\\YandexDisk\\latest version\\CF Distribution\\Debug\\CF Distribution.exe\"";
path2 = "C:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\Monday\\case";
path = path1 + " " + path2 + " " + to_string(cn);
CreateProcess(NULL, const_cast<LPSTR>(path.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

// Закрываю дискрипоры процесса и потока
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

system("pause");
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Хэндлы закрываются тогда, когда в них пропадает необходимость
2. Закрытие хэндлов процессов и потоков не приводит к завершению этих процессов и потоков
3. Использование структуры как out параметра приводит к перезаписыванию полей структуры и потере предыдущих значений.

Исходя из всего сказанного, правильный код будет выглядеть так

```
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, const_cast<LPSTR>(path.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
  // Ошибка. Процесс не запустился. Закрывать нечего. Код ошибки вернет GetLastError
} else {
  // Дескриптор потока нам не нужен
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
  // Ждем завершения процесса
  WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
  // Дескриптор процесса уже не нужен
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}

// Запускаем следующий процесс
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, const_cast<LPSTR>(path.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
  // Ошибка. Процесс не запустился. Закрывать нечего. Код ошибки вернет GetLastError
} else {
  // Дескриптор потока нам не нужен
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
  // Ждем завершения процесса
  WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
  // Дескриптор процесса уже не нужен
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```